# How to set a combobox size to the maximum width of its content?

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

I have this ComboBox

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo.Bars}"/>
```

Can I set the size of the combobox to the width of its widest item?

For example, if the contents are:

```
John Doe
Jane Mary
Josh
```

The length would be equal to the length of Jane Mary.

Also, in this case the contents are not expected to change after initialization

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is make a converter that would return the longest length of one your object property. You can implement the converter like this:

```
public class LongestListObjectToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable<FooBar>)
        {
            IEnumerable<FooBar> list = (IEnumerable<FooBar>)value;

            return list.Max(bar => bar.FullName.Length);
        }

        // Default value to return
        return 100;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then simply bind the Width property of your ComboBox by provinding the list as the Path binding and your converter as a value converter.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:LongestListObjectToIntConverter x:Key=converter/>
</Windows.Resources>

    ...

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo.Bars}" Width="{Binding Path=Foo.Bars, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
```

This way, even if your collection changes and this changes are not notified, the ComboBox would resize depending on the longest word.

Another interesting idea would be to make a self binding on Width and grab the actual combobox in the converter to then inspect the displayed value, that would be even better I think.

The advantage of this solution is that uses no code-behind and is easily reusable. You can find more information on ValueConverters here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: why do you think my object has the `FullName` property? If the object is a string, how can I convert the string length to pixels?

Comment: I used FullName arbitrarly. You can use any property you want or even combine them like : bar => (bar.FirstName + bar.LastName).Lenght. Have also a look at the additional solution I gave you.

Comment: Which additional solution? If I use a string, for a name like "Jane Mary" will return 9 (9 characters), but I think the actual pixel width is larger than that

Comment: The additional solution I gave is actually the one ArsenMkrt just gave you. Follow this guy ;) Of course for the size, you will have to add additional pixels depending on the border thickness and the width of the expander of your ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

You can write converter like this

```
 public class ComboBoxToMaxItemWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double maxWidth = 0;
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)value;
        foreach (var item in cb.Items)
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbItem = (ComboBoxItem)cb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (cbItem.ActualWidth > maxWidth)
                maxWidth = cbItem.ActualWidth;
        }
        return maxWidth;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use it

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo.Bars}" Width={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource comboBoxToMaxItemWidthConverter }/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That is just the best way to do it. I guess. Just add some additonal pixel because of the expander and border thickness of the ComboBox.

Comment: I got compile error on this line

    `ComboBoxItem cbItem = cb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item); `

something about type mismatch. How to fix it?

Comment: oops sorry, I wrote code here manually so didn't note error, fixed now

Comment: I treid using that, but cbItem is null (even though item is not and cb.Items has 2 members), any idea why this happens?

Comment: Looks like it is not working, because the converter is called before items are bound to the combo box.

Answer (score 2):

@ArsenMkrt: cbItem is null due to know issue in SL (here the link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687691/silverlight-4-5-beta-combobox-itemcontainergenerator-methods-return-null-and-not-a-combboxitem). Therefore, this is not a working solution right now.

@YogWiN: usually, the items of combobox are model objects (from ItemsSource binding), not a ComboBoxItem controls like you assume in your answer. Therefore you can't iterate an items collection.

In addition I tried to override PrepareContainerForItemOverride method on ComboBox, but elements have no width until displayed in dropdown list. Also I tried to switch default panel by my own, but MeasureOverride being called only when the dropdown list is opened...

So as far as I know, today, you cannot do it with the ComboBox control.

Answer (score -1):

The DropDownWidth can be used to set the width from code behind. Use following links for reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownwidth%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ComboBoxAutoWidth.aspx

However, this will set the size only for dropdown part.

Comment: That is for Windows Forms, not WPF.